# Hide displayed variation cutom fields data when empty in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, templates, woocommerce, product-variations

I add custom fields to product variations ([thanks to this post](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/add-custom-fields-to-product-variations.html?unapproved=8310&moderation-hash=ec4019fd4c28cf942c7b54576ea20cdc))

I add this code in wp-content\themes\my_theme\woocommerce\single-product\add-to-cart\product-attributes.php template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Product attributes
 * @version 3.6.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! $product_attributes ) {
    return;
}
?>


<ul id="new_product_attributes" class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
        
        <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Caratteristiche tecniche</a>
        
        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>

            <div class="attributes_container">
                <table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
                    
                    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
                        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
                            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
                            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                </table>
            </div>


            <div class="single_variation_wrap">
                <div id="variation_clone_box" class="woocommerce-variation single_variation">

                    <script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">

                    
                        <table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">

                            <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--my_field">
                                <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">My Field Label</th>
                                <td id="my_field" class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">{{{ data.variation.my_field }}}</td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                        
                        <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
                        <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}</div>
                        <div id="old_box_Price" class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>

                    </script>

                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="datasheets_box">
                <a class="button">(i) Scarica la scheda tecnica</a>
            </div>


            <div class="richiedi_info_box">
                <p class="richiedi_info_title">Richiedi informazioni</p>

                <p><strong>Assistenza Clienti</strong></p>
                <p>
                    ORARI<br>
                    Dal Lunedì al Venerdì<br>
                    8:00 / 13:00 - 14:00 / 17:00
                <p>
                    <a class="button">(i) assistenza@grafoplast.it</a>
                    &nbsp;
                    <a class="button">(i) +39 0131 718477</a>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div><!-- accordion-content -->
    </li>

</ul><!-- #new_product_attributes -->


<div id="new_box_AddToCart">

    <?php
    woocommerce_quantity_input(
        array(
            'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), // WPCS: CSRF ok, input var ok.
        )
    );
    ?>
    <div class="shipment_info">
        <p>Disponibilità immediata</p>
        <p>I costi di spedizione sono esclusi</p>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt<?php echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
</div>
```

This works very well!

In the code above I add many rows. Each line corresponds to a new custom field.
To simplify, in this post I paste only one row with only one custom field.
The code below is the part of table to hide ...if custom field is empty.

```
<tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--my_field">
   <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">My Field Label</th>
   <td id="my_field" class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">
      {{{ data.variation.my_field }}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

If {{{ data.variation.my_field }}} is empty, Woocommerce shows the row. I've many custom fields in product variations ([see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDBF4.png)) so I try to show only the rows with a value.

I would like to hide the row if {{{ data.variation.my_field }}} is empty.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
{{{ #if data.variation.my_field }}}

   <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--my_field">
      <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">My Field</th>
      <td id="your_field" class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">
         {{{ data.variation.my_field }}}
      </td>
   </tr>

{{{/if }}}
```

**How to Add Custom Fields to Product Variations (this part works)**

Now I write you all the code that I used to add custom field to product variations. I don't know if it can help you to solve the problem ;)

To add custom field for variations I wrote this in function.php.

I create new custom field for variations (here called "My Field"):

```
function my_field_settings( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'            => "my_field{$loop}",
            'label'         => __( 'My Field', 'woocommerce' ),
            'name'          => "my_field[{$loop}]",
            'value'         => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'my_field', true ),
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-33',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'my_field_settings', 10, 3 );
```

After, I save the new custom field:

```
function my_field_save( $variation_id, $loop ) {
   $text_field = $_POST['my_field'][ $loop ];
   update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'my_field', esc_attr( $text_field ));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'my_field_save', 10, 2 );
```

At the end I add my new custom field:

```
function my_field_load( $variation ) {     
    $variation['my_field'] = get_post_meta( $variation[ 'variation_id' ], 'my_field', true );
    return $variation;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'my_field_load' );
```

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec. I add all related code to the post and I add the attachment.

Comment: I don't understand how to hide the empty rows. I suppose Woocommerce uses Handlebars to show the custom fields but I don't know handlebars.js ...I try to use {{{ #if myfield }}} {{{ /if myfield }}} but doesn't work.

Comment: In product-attributes.php file. I made a copy of original file and paste it in my theme

Comment: I updated the post: now you can see the complete product-attributes.php template

Comment: OK thanks I get it working… I answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have revisited all your code, using WooCommerce CRUD Methods and latest WooCommerce hooks.

I have added some jQuery code to allow showing or hiding the "Diametro nominale" display.

I have shortened the code on the template...

Here is that code:

```php
function add_admin_variation_custom_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    $variation_object = wc_get_product($variation->ID);

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => "diametro_nominale_{$loop}",
        'label'         => __( 'Diametro nominale', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'         => $variation_object->get_meta('diametro_nominale'),
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-33',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'add_admin_variation_custom_fields', 10, 3 );


function save_admin_variation_custom_fields( $variation, $i ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['diametro_nominale_'.$i]) ) {
        $variation->update_meta_data('diametro_nominale', sanitize_text_field($_POST['diametro_nominale_'.$i]));
    }
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'save_admin_variation_custom_fields', 10, 2 );


function display_variation_custom_field_values( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {   
    $diametro_nominale = $variation->get_meta('diametro_nominale');
    $variation_data['diametro_nominale'] = empty($diametro_nominale) ? 0 : $diametro_nominale;

    return $variation_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_custom_field_values', 10, 3 );


function variation_custom_fields_js() {   
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        // After DOM (on load)
        $('.shop_attributes .diametro-nominale').hide();

        // On Selected variation or Unselected variation
        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
            // On variation "show"
            if ( data.diametro_nominale == '0' ) {
                // When "diametro_nominale" is empty
                $('.shop_attributes .diametro-nominale').hide();
            } else {
                // When "diametro_nominale" has data
                $('.shop_attributes .diametro-nominale').show();
            }
        }).on('hide_variation', function(){
            // On variations "Hide"
            $('.shop_attributes .diametro-nominale').hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'variation_custom_fields_js' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

And the shortened code for `single-product/product-attributes.php` template file:

```html
?>
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<div class="single_variation_wrap">
    <div id="variation_clone_box" class="woocommerce-variation single_variation">
        <script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
            <table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
                <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--diametro_nominale diametro-nominale">
                    <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php _e( 'Diametro nominale', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">{{{ data.variation.diametro_nominale }}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
            <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}</div>
            <div id="old_box_Price" class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tested and works.

Comment: I used your your code and work for me! Many thanks @LoicTheAztec